# RelativeLayout centering items not working

Tags: android

I have the following code that has a `TextView` and a `Button`. Both of them should look centered:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/register_background"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_NoProfile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:text="No items in profiles database." />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonAddProfile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_style"
    android:text="Add profile"
    android:layout_below="@id/text_NoProfile"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But when I go to the view, it looks like this:

[image]

Why is it not aligned? I thought the **gravity="center_horizontal"** should do the trick...

Comment: where is the listview with id listView_users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gravity = "center_horizontal"` will not work because the parent of your RelativeLayout is not LinearLayout nor FrameLayout, you should use `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` instead like the following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/register_background"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_NoProfile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="No items in profiles database." />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonAddProfile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_style"
    android:text="Add profile"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/listView_users"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember always, in RelativeLayout **gravity** attribute is not available, that's why its is not working. To make elements center aligned specify **layout_centerHorizontal** attribute as true.Otherwise take LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Add
`android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`
to both elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:gravity="center">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_NoProfile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:text="No items in profiles database."
    android:gravity="center"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text_NoProfile"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```